# Mongodb\BSON\Regex Php: Perform Like Match

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I see these links:

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#regular-expressions
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-a-like-match

On mongo terminal regex "/giov/i" Found:

- Mariogiovanni
- Giovanni

On php with

```
$cursor = $collection->find([
    'description' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex(' /giov/', 'i'),

]);
```

nothing coming back. Why? I try some solution find on this community but nothing

Comment: You should try as shown in the docs: `new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('giov', 'i')`

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor  work very well. Personally I think that mongodb/ php docs are poor of examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the regex delimiters since they are not used in `MongoDB\BSON\Regex`:

```
$cursor = $collection->find([
    'description' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('giov', 'i'),

]);
```

The answer is quite evident if you follow your first [reference link](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#regular-expressions):

> The following example lists documents in the zips collection where the city name starts with “garden” and the state is Texas:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> $collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->test->zips;
>
> $cursor = $collection->find([
>     'city' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^garden', 'i'),
>     'state' => 'TX',
> ]);
>
> foreach ($cursor as $document) {
>    printf("%s: %s, %s\n", $document['_id'], $document['city'], $document['state']);
> }
> ```